# How to add a view in all view controllers from a view Controller

Tags: ios, swift3

[player View Controller Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4lHS.png)
I am developing a Audio Player Application in swift 3 . I have a Player view controller which have some audio Control buttons and this view controller connected with others 'play list'  view controller .  From my home and other view controller  I make this player view controller appears as 'present modally' . Now when I back/ go to another view without making player stop I need to add a  common view that has 'Stop Button' and other audio controller and appears in all the view controllers. (It has Background Audio Compatibility)
I'm a new comer in swift.Trying to figure out all the steps to do that.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution maybe to make the player view controller just a view instead of a view controller. You'd do that by making it a xib. From all your view controllers you could add this player xib as a subView to the view controller. This depends on how many view controllers you have. You'd also need a service that in the background updates the player view. This could be done with notifications, where notifications could be sent out from the player controller logic and the view controllers would receive the player updates notifications and in turn update the player view. A bit hard to explain in a paragraph.

Comment: well , There are more than 10 view controller connected with this player view controller . So , this is not time efficient in my present situation . Is there any other solution ?  Here is my Player view Controller snap : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4lHS.png

Comment: Yes that's a lot of VCs. I assume however you could use an extension for ViewController and it could end up making it not that bad. The extension would have to code to add the player as a subview, as well as handle the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about UI design than it is about Swift.  One possibility would be to create a container view controller that owns your audio controls and has a container view for the various other view controllers that you have to display.

(See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

The container controller would manage the visibility of the controls and the amount of space allocated to them and to the content views.